# C++ Chat client missing lib file

Tags: c++

I have made a chat program with using Winsock2.h and the lib file ws2_32.lib. 
When I want to test the chat program out on a computer on another network, it shows me a message box with the text:
"The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".

How do I make my program able to run on all windows 7 machines without having to install Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi, what is missing in the destination machine is NOT whole Visual Studio but the Visual C++ runtime which could be distributed with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a setup project which includes the required libraries and installs them in the client machine during your application's setup.

In fact you need a setup anyway if you want to create a shortcut to your program in the Start Menu or on the desktop for example.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, but theres just one more thing.
How do I know which files to include? And do I have to copy them from system folder?

I'm just a little confused, because when I write #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib"), I thought it would just be the ws2_32.lib, and not some MSVCR100.dll...

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to install Visual Studio, You do need to make sure all of your program's dependencys are on the destination computer. You would normally do this by creating a setup program. The dll that you are missing MSVCR100.dll can be found as part of the [VC++ redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

Answer (score 0):

You need the redistributable package for your visual studio version. For VS2010 (x86) can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5555

Alternatively, you can create an installer that will include the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Your program depends on the Visual C++ [redistributal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).  You will need to bundle it with your programs installer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, but theres just one more thing. How do I know which files to include? And do I have to copy them from system folder? I'm just a little confused, because when I write #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib"), I thought it would just be the ws2_32.lib, and not some MSVCR100.dll...